# how to add control runtime(dynamically)

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to add control(textbox ,button "Remove") 3times in runtime with the help of add button.
and adding someting text in text box but when i am clicking button "Remove" then all added control goes to erase.

how to achiev solution for this problem ?

```
 Button btn = new Button();
                 Table tblName = new Table();
                 PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1 = new PlaceHolder();
                 btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
                 TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                 tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                 tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                 tr.Cells[0].Text ="jhjh";
                 tr.Cells[1].Controls.Add(btn);
                 btn.Text = "Remove";
                // btn.ID = "Remove_0";
                 tblName.Rows.Add(tr);
                 PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tblName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Controls added dynamically, must be re-created each time (and prefererably on the Page_Init before the ViewState is parsed)

Comment: how to re-created control in page-init.?how to maintain the state  of all added contorl

Comment: Using the same code you supplied in the Page_Init will ensure your controls will stay even after a post-back, AND because the Page_Init is prior to the ViewState parsing, in the Page_Load and other events the control's state will be as you expect it to be

Comment: i have added event handler like this way btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click); but handle is not be fired.